# Transition to the integral in inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Prove or disprove by counterexample the statement: $(\forall x \in [a; b]$ $f(x) < g(x))\Rightarrow $
$$\Rightarrow (\int_{a}^bf(x)dx < \int_{a}^bg(x)dx)$$
Of course, f and g are integrable on [a; b].

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Sure, I've tried to disprove it by counterexample but, unforunately,  I haven't find the correct one...

Comment: Have you tried proving it true? Also, you should edit any work you've done into the question.

Comment: Hint: Ask yourself can you construct a function which is strictly positive but may have a zero area.

Comment: Thank you, Anurag A!